# MEAN.js Injecting Module throws Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, meanjs

I am building an app with MEAN.js and I am trying to add https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert

The first thing I did was to edit the config/env/all.js file to include the javascript files for SweetAlert

I then edited the public/dist/application.js file to add the "oitozero.ngSweetAlert" module as follows:

var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'];

Now in my controller I try to add the module, and once I do this I get the Unknown Provider error:

```
angular.module('stock').controller('myController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$http', '$modal', 'Authentication', 'Stock', 'Users', 'SweetAlert',


function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, $modal, Authentication, Stock, Users, SweetAlert) {
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong. TIA!

Comment: Have you tried to restart your mean.js app?

Comment: @geniuscarrier Yes for sure, I am running it with grunt so the app restarts on every change, but I also restarted it manually

Comment: Which mean.js version are you using? Mean.js version 0.3.0 uses Angular version 1.2.28. But ngSweetAlert is depending on Angular version 1.3.0. See this: https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert/blob/master/bower.json#L28

Comment: Yes it does look like I am running an old version of mean.js. It looks like they have changed many things in version 0.4 so it will take me a a while to upgrade. I will post the results after I have upgraded